# How to get to a desired expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm confused with the $\frac{x}{6}(x+1)(2x+1)+(x+1)^2$ expression, I'm trying to get to the desired expression by simplifying, which is this: (x+1)/6(x+2)(2x+3)
I saw in a youtube video how this expression is simplified, and the author takes those steps:
$$=\frac{(x+1)}{6} x(2x+1) + \frac{6(x+1)^2}{6}\\
=\frac{x+1}{6}[x(2x+1)+6(x+1)]\\
=\frac{x+1}{6}(2x^2+x+6x+6)\\
=\frac{x+1}{6}(2x^2+7x+6)\\
=\frac{x+1}{6}(x+2)(2x+3)$$
My question is, how he comes from step 1 to step 2 so how does he get rid from that square and from that 6 denominator, from $\frac{6(x+1)^2}{6}$ to $6(x+1)$ ?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am confused be your first expression. :)

Comment: You hast have to factor out $(x+1)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The step you do not understand is
$$\frac{(x+1)}{6} x(2x+1) + \frac{6(x+1)^2}{6}=\frac{x+1}{6}[x(2x+1)+6(x+1)]$$
is it?

In this step you just have to *factor out* the term $\frac16(x+1)$

First write $(x+1)^2$ as $(x+1)(x+1)$
$$\frac{(x+1)}{6} x(2x+1) + \frac{6\color{red}{(x+1)^2}}{6}= \frac{(x+1)}{6} x(2x+1) + \frac{6\color{red}{(x+1)(x+1)}}{6}$$

Now you are able to factor out the term $\frac16(x+1)$

$$\color{red}{\frac{(x+1)}{6}} x(2x+1) + \frac{6\color{red}{(x+1)}(x+1)}{\color{red}{6}} = \color{red}{\frac{(x+1)}6}\cdot\left[x(2x+1)+6(x+1) \right]$$

Comment: We have two (x+1)/6, at the end you leave just one, how does the first (x+1)/6 disappear? 
Thank you, again!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, we have $$\frac{x}{6}(x+1)(2x+1)+(x+1)^2\to(x+1)\left[\frac{x}{6}(2x+1)+(x+1)\right]\\ =(x+1)\left[\frac{2x^2+x}{6}+(x+1)\right]=(x+1)\left[\frac{2x^2+x+6x+6}{6}\right]=(x+1)\left[\frac{2x^2+7x+6}{6}\right]$$ and for the final polynomial $2x^2+7x+6$ we have $2x^2+7x+6=(x+3/2)(x+2)$.

Answer (score 2):

What the author is doing here is factoring out $\frac{x+1}6$ from the two expressions. Indeed, $$\frac{6(x+1)^2}6=\frac{6(x+1)(x+1)}6=\frac{x+1}{6}\cdot 6(x+1),$$ so $$\frac{x+1}6\cdot x(2x+1)+\frac{6(x+1)^2}6=\frac{x+1}6\bigl(x(2x+1)+6(x+1)\bigr).$$